# Originate command with originate_retries in Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

While executing the below command on Freeswitch, I got the 4 times retry to 1002 while I set it to only 2 times.

**originate {ignore_early_media=true,originate_continue_on_timeout=true,originate_timeout=30,originate_retries=2,originate_retry_sleep_ms=60000}user/1002 &bridge(user/1005)**

Can anyone suggest me about this problem?

Comment: What happens if you set the retried to 1?

Comment: it will not retries.

Comment: @suren did the given answer solved your problem..!

Answer (score 1):

`originate_continue_on_timeout` will reset your timeout, so remove it from `global` variable. Probably what you want is

> {ignore_early_media=true,originate_timeout=30,originate_retries=2,originate_retry_sleep_ms=60000}user/1002
>   &bridge({originate_continue_on_timeout=true,originate_timeout=30}user/1005)

Not tested it but should work

Comment: its working for if no answer by the extension on retry but it should also work on retry on busy.if call is busy then it again retry more then retries.

Comment: @suren ```originate_continue_on_timeout``` primary purpose is to dial next extension(user) if cant connect to current one...I would suggest you to try with 2 3 extension(user), and to check if other user is getting connected in case of first one got timeout.

Comment: thanks for your information but solution is done by myself.basically what i was doing using currly braces to set origination_retries but there should be square bracket. and our concern was not about originate_continue_on_timeout.

Comment: so i mentioned in answer that dont use it  ```globaly```...```[]``` is used to define variable ```locally```. You can either use ```[]``` or define variable with each ```leg```. Anyways happy that you solved your problem... :)